# Will Workbooks("ABC.xlsx").Close work between different PC?

Tags: excel, vba

Can i close the excel file opened in another PC using the command Workbooks("ABC.xlsx").close from my PC when our PC'S are connected by a network and the excel file is stored in a common network location?

Comment: You want to control the Excel application running on another machine?

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for ur reply. Can you please explain what you exactly mean by this "So long as you managed to open the file"?

Comment: @VinodChelladurai: apologies, I misread the question and so my deleted answer was misleading. Could you please answer dwo's comment? I think you can address this using DCOM (distributed COM).

Comment: this may help: [how to list the user's that have opened a specified shared workbook and how to disconnect specified users](http://www.vbusers.com/code/codeget.asp?ThreadID=512&PostID=1)

Comment: @dwo..Yes..I mean i want to close an application on another machine from my machine...And this application will be in a common network location and the macro that i use to close will also be in that location

Comment: @simoco...I dont want to disconnect any user because user's login here is out of scope. I just want to close the workbook

Comment: `disconnect user` in this context means close shared workbook from his/her PC

Comment: That is not working perfectly for me

Comment: Any other suggestions please?

Comment: vinod what is not working in regards to what was suggested? did you get errors did nothing happen, what was the problem?

Comment: Hello...Am getting wrong result for that